# Twitter API v2 User's received Likes count

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to retrieve the total count of the number of Likes a User has received with the v2 API, without authenticating with the user?

Typically, anything that's publicly visible on Twitter (X) is available. For instance, the followers and following counts are available via the `User` object's `public_metrics` property.

The Like count is available on a User's page at the top, after clicking the "Likes" tab, but I can't see a way to retrieve just the count. The `Likes` endpoint permits retrieving all of the liked Tweets, but there's limits and pagination to deal with, when all I need is a simple summary count.